# Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGABRT

Tags: node.js, linux, debian, forever

I randomly see this error in my NodeJS, running via forever:

```
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGABRT
error: Script restart attempt #12
error: Forever detected script was killed by signal: SIGABRT
error: Script restart attempt #13
```

It happens once or twice per week, that's it. And is restarted right after and then runs fine.

How/what can I do, to debug or fix such error?

I'm running NodeJS 6 and Debian 8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11161126/what-causes-a-sigabrt-fault